# clojure vector cache

Tags: caching, clojure, fifo

I'm looking for a cache that behaves like a vector. I've been using [core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache) but those are maps. I just need a simple fifo eviction method. I realize that I can simply create my own using the `CacheProtocol` protocol but I wanted to know if something like this already exists or if there's a reason this is a bad idea.

Comment: Just to see is I understand the question; do you want the contents of a vector to be cached where the element at each index is replaced with  new values when they become available?

Comment: ya that's what I was looking for. However I didn't think the about the overhead that shifting all the elements would introduce. This answers the last part of my question: "is this a bad idea?" => "yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a vector like interface to a cache then it is likely that a cache of indexes to values will suit your needs. I'm guessing a bit about your specific problem though it seems likely that using **numbers as the keys to your cache would fill many use cases** because vectors are conceptually very similar to maps of numbers to values:

```
user> (def C (cache/fifo-cache-factory {0 1 1 0}))
user> (get C 0)
1
```

if that is not enough then you could look at the current contents of your cache in the form of a vector like so:

```
user> (vec (map #(get C % nil) (range 11)))
[1 0 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil]
```

in most cases it's likely that using numbers as indexes will do the job for many people